# LaTex error please help

Tags: errors, equations

I'm a beginner at LaTeX and I get a LaTeX error when I type this:

```
\begin{equation}
{$k = \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta I} $}
\end{equation}
```

Could someone tell me what to do?

Comment: You don't need `$` in an equation environment, so just remove them and try again. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple typo.  `$` does not belong inside the `equation` environment.

Comment: @HenriMenke To be fair, I don't think it's a typo, but a beginner's misunderstanding. That said, I'm sure it's a duplicate multiple times over

Comment: As said by @awllower you must not have `$` within the `equation` environment, `equation` is a math mode environment. You also don't need `{ ... }` around the whole lot, they aren't doing anything for you